# How to implement anonymous authorization using Supabase?

Tags: authentication, supabase

Is there a way to implement anonymous authorization using [Supabase](https://supabase.com/)?

I have a mobile app and I want to implement the following functionality:
Every user should have an account on the server right after the app installed. I'll use Device id as the primary identifier. This will create a temporary account. And when the user signs the ToS, it will be converted to a full-fledged account. So, I need a possibility to create a temporary account using Supabase. I didn't find anything related to this problem in the documentation.

I know that in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) there is [a similar feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

Can you help? Is it even possible to implement this using Supabase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an existing feature request:

https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/68

The issue above references a possible way to do this now (there are probably other ways to do this as well):

> this is possible today by choosing a random email address and
> disabling email confirmations / you can then later update the email
> address

Comment: Will it be possible even with google auth later?